# android edittext (Number validation) cannot return value from a method with void result type

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.crazywriteup.getbmi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MaleActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    EditText enm,ehgf,ehgi,ewg;
    Button btnmale;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_male);

        enm = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mleditText);
        ehgf = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mleditText2);
        ehgi = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mleditText3);
        ewg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mleditText4);
        btnmale = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnmlsubmit);

        btnmale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if(enm.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PLS FILL NAME",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    // Nothing
                    ehgf.requestFocus();
                }

            }

        });


        public  boolean isNum(String val)
        {
            boolean check = false;
            String no = "\\d*\\.?\\d+";
            CharSequence inputstr = val;
            Pattern pte = Pattern.compile(no,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            Matcher matcher = pte.matcher(inputstr);
            if(matcher.matches())
            {
                check = true;
            }
            return check;
        }

    }

}
```

I am working on android number textbox () I want to set the range 1 to 7 but I am facing difficulty in programming code. It always shows the error `cannot return a value from a method with void result type`. I am a beginner & don't have much knowledge about programming.

Comment: You have implemented the method `public  boolean isNum(String val)` inside the scope of `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`, that's why your IDE / compiler says you cannot return a value from a method with void result type.

Comment: formatting, grammar and slight rewording to make it easier to read and follow

Comment: you can't declare method inside another method.

Answer (score 1):

The **`onCreate()`** method **`return void`** and you are trying to return `boolean`

You need to create your **`isNum()`** method outside the **`onCreate()`**

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
public class MaleActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    EditText enm,ehgf,ehgi,ewg;
    Button btnmale;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_male);

        enm = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mleditText);
        ehgf = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mleditText2);
        ehgi = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mleditText3);
        ewg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mleditText4);
        btnmale = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnmlsubmit);

        btnmale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if(enm.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PLS FILL NAME",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    // Nothing
                    ehgf.requestFocus();
                }

            }

        });




    }
        public  boolean isNum(String val)
        {
            boolean check = false;
            String no = "\\d*\\.?\\d+";
            CharSequence inputstr = val;
            Pattern pte = Pattern.compile(no,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            Matcher matcher = pte.matcher(inputstr);
            if(matcher.matches())
            {
                check = true;
            }
            return check;
        }

}
```